# My external HDD not mounting and not being seen

Tags: mount, ntfs, external-hdd

So a few months back I was using my Toshiba 1Tb external HDD and when I was done I unmounted it before taking 'Safely Remove Drive'. Not thirty minutes later when I went to reconnect it, it wouldn't read. I connected it to my windows machine (which has since crashed) and it tried to run chkdsk but there was no drive letter assigned to it. In diskpart, it was visible but any action I tried to take such as assigning it a letter all failed.
I tried a variety of options which probably worsened the solution including using TestDisk and Disk Drill in attempts to fix what I thought were bad sectors but a power outage prevented both from completing. Now the Drive still appears when I run lsblk on Ubuntu but it shows it has no partition. It doesn't even show up on Diskpart anymore. What can I do to fix this without losing everything on the Drive?

NOTE: At some point when I went to Disk Management (before the power outage), it told me to initialize the disk and displayed all of it's space as unallocated but I knew if I initialized it then I would lose everything so I didn't but not that option doesn't even come up because the disk doesn't even appear in disk management when I connected it to a friend's Windows.

PLEASE HELP. I would really love any and all feedback on those who might've faced similar issues.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Which file system is being used on the external device? NTFS? Something else?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].